# Storyboard layout differs between simulator and device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I have a problem where the design from the storyboard is great in the iPhone 5s simulator, but on my 5s, it is pushed down, and the bottom is cut off:

Simulator:
[image: simulator]

Device:
[image: device]

Any ideas as to how or why it is doing this? My storyboard settings are:

[image: settings]

**ViewController Code**

```
@IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var btnRegister: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnRecoverPassword: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var loading: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet var fbLoginView : FBLoginView!
var actionView: UIView = UIView()
var window: UIWindow? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//        var delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
//        var myWindow: UIWindow? = delegate.keyWindow
//        var myWindow2: NSArray = delegate.windows

    window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

    loading.hidden = true

    // change the textfield colours
    txtUsername.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    txtPassword.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.45)

    self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
    self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    actionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height.0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 260.0)
}
```

Comment: You need to add the 4" launch image to get rid of the black bars.

Comment: How did you add it? Does it have the correct name? Case in the filename matters on a device.

Comment: @rmaddy In the general settings, I included the storyboard that I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having this issue, it seems that it is a problem with xcode itself, as I recreated the project in one of the beta versions, then opened it in xcode 6, and it worked fine. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a app for 3.5 inch, that's crazy. Your storyboard settings are exactly like mine.

Did you try to build with the Iphone 3.5 inch size and come back to the 4inch size?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but still the same result, I deleted the storyboard and tried recreating it, I tried rebooting my phone, nothing seems to be working

Comment: Please see updated question, I added the view controller code

Comment: I just created a new project, and it did the exact same thing. Could it possibly be an issue with xcode?

Comment: yes I do, That is the only one I have installed on my mac

Comment: is your view mode is Scale yo Fill?

Comment: yes it is. It has to be a storyboard problem, because it still happens with no class/view controller assigned